# Why deployment sh script don't fails on failed nginx reloading?

Tags: nginx, bash, deployment

I have sh script that restart nginx like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

set -e

error_exit() {
    d=$(date '+%D %T :: ')
    echo "$d Error: $*" >&2

    exit 1
}

if ! sudo service nginx reload
then        
    # Exit with error
    error_exit "Could not reload nginx"
fi

echo "Deployment Done!"
```

But my problem is that script continues execution event in case error like `Reloading nginx configuration nginx [fail]` and reaches `Deployment Done!` echo. It's seems if case is always `true`.

So, how could I stop executing of bash script if nginx reloading fails?

Comment: It's a sh script.

Comment: Yes sure, I've edited the the post

Comment: testing for > 0 would be a good idea (since 0 means success).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `exit 1` by `return` and insert a line before `fi` with `exit 1`.

**Update:**

Try this with a GNU grep:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

set -e

error_exit() {
    d=$(date '+%D %T :: ')
    echo "$d Error: $*" >&2

    exit 1
}

out="$(sudo service nginx reload 2>&1 | grep -o fail || true)"  # new
if [ "x$out" = "xfail" ]                                        # modified
then
    # Exit with error
    error_exit "Could not reload nginx"
fi

echo "Deployment Done!"
```

Comment: unfortunately your magic doesn't work :(

Comment: What's the returncode (`echo $?`) of `sudo service nginx reload` if reload fails?

Comment: nothing because `sudo service nginx reload` case is always `true` and don't get stepped into body clause.

Comment: okay, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I'll try a little bit later. Is this preferable approach? Is there any best practices in checking result of such commands?

Comment: Usually in case of success the returncode is 0 and in case of failure the returncode is unequal 0.